# Upgrade Jekyll from 0.12.1 to 1.0.0 categories have double url

Tags: jekyll

We have a pretty basic Jekyll site, lots of posts all divided up into categories. We're using the [generate categories](https://github.com/recurser/jekyll-plugins/blob/master/generate_categories.rb) plugin.

Our categories were accessible at http://fake.com/categories/cat_index

After upgrading from 0.12.1 to 1.0.0, all of the category posts now have a url of http://fake.com/categories/cat_index/categories/cat_index

The only big thing I know changes between versions was the addition of the baseUrl being exposed to the liquid templates, but I can't figure out how that would have affected the post generation.

Searching this site and the rest of the internet I haven't been able to find anyone else having a similar error. I tried using a different category plugin, but had the same error.

A stripped version of the _congig.yml (just took out actual category/post names to maintain client anonymity)

```
exclude: [Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, Procfile]
safe: false
permalink: /:title
pygments: false
source:      .
destination: ./_site
plugins:     ./_plugins
relative_permalinks: false


primary_nav:
  - label: 'Home'
    href: ''


secondary_nav:
#  - label: 'Example 1'
#    href: link1.html
#  - label: 'Example 2'
#    href: link2.html


sections:
  - key: 'fake'
    label: 'Fake'
    children:
      - key: 'post-title'
        label: 'Post Title'
  - key: 'fake2'
    label: 'Fake2'
    children:
      - key: 'post-title2'
        label: 'Post Title2'

# configs for unwrapped.rb plugin
unwrapped_dest_directory: 'unwrapped'
unwrapped_template_path: '_includes/styleguide'
unwrapped_template_file: 'unwrapped.html'
```

Comment: Do the posts or the category page have a wrong URL ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: The posts have the wrong URLs. Not just URL though, the files are being generated in that double nested directory structure.

Comment: So it had nothing to see with your generate categories plugin, IMHO. It just generates index pages.

Comment: Can we see source somewhere ? It has to do with permalinks configuration, probably.

Comment: We have the permalinks in the _config.yml as `permalink: /:title` and we don't use permalink in the yaml front matter of the pages.

Comment: So it should not even be `/categories/post` but `/post`. Can you show your config ?

Comment: I'm really not sure we understand each others =) Is it your posts or your categories index page whose URL changed ?

Comment: Ah sorry. This is my first fore into Jekyll, so my nomenclature was off. It is the category index pages that are off. I've edited my post example URLs to reflect this.